Step-by-step sort (Ardalis.Specification)
Before this I used such a function to sort data:
    public Func<IQueryable<FileModel>, IQueryable<FileModel>> SortFiles(int? userId, int? skip, int? count, bool byDesc, string? type, string? mime, string? category)
    {
        IQueryable<FileModel> sortedQuery;

        Func<IQueryable<FileModel>, IQueryable<FileModel>> sortDelegate = query =>
        {
            sortedQuery = byDesc ? query.OrderByDescending(f => f.operation_date) : query.OrderBy(f => f.operation_date);

            if (userId.HasValue)
                sortedQuery = sortedQuery.Where(f => f.user_id.Equals(userId));

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(type))
                sortedQuery = sortedQuery.Where(f => f.type.Equals(type));

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(category))
                sortedQuery = sortedQuery.Where(f => f.file_mime_category.Equals(category));

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mime))
                sortedQuery = sortedQuery.Where(f => f.file_mime.Equals(mime));

            if (skip.HasValue && count.HasValue)
                sortedQuery = sortedQuery.Skip(skip.Value).Take(count.Value);

            return sortedQuery;
        };

        return sortDelegate;
    }

But now I’m switching to Ardalis.Specification lib, and this function no longer suits me, I want to sort via Specification ctor,
like that:
public class FilesSortSpecification : Specification<FileModel>
{
    public FilesSortSpecification(int? userId, int? skip, int? count, bool byDesc, string? type, string? mime, string? category)
    {
        if (byDesc)
            Query.OrderByDescending(f => f.operation_date);
        else
            Query.OrderBy(f => f.operation_date);

        if (userId.HasValue)
            Query.Where(f => f.user_id.Equals(userId));

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(type))
            Query.Where(f => f.type.Equals(type));

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(category))
            Query.Where(f => f.file_mime_category.Equals(category));

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mime))
            Query.Where(f => f.file_mime.Equals(mime));

        if (skip.HasValue && count.HasValue)
            Query.Skip(skip.Value).Take(count.Value);
    }
}

But I don't know if the value of the Query object created in the previous sort step will be preserved or for each step of the subsequent sort step the value from the Query will be overwritten ?
Will it be necessary to create many specification objects, or will my version work correctly?
